# How to normalize group by count results?

Tags: postgresql

How can the results of a "group by" count be normalized by the count's sum?

For example, given:

```
User     Rating (1-5)
----------------------
1        3
1        4
1        2
3        5
4        3
3        2
2        3
```

The result will be:

```
User    Count   Percentage
---------------------------
1       3      .42         (=3/7)
2       1      .14         (=1/7)
3       2      .28         (...)
4       1      .14
```

So for each user the number of ratings they provided is given as the percentage of the total ratings provided by everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user) user, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS cnt,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user) / count(*) OVER () AS percentage;
```

The `count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user)` is a so-called [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). Window functions let you perform some operation over a "window" created by some "partition" which is here made over the user id. In plain and simple English: the partitioned `count(*)` is calculated for each distinct `user` value, so in effect it counts the number of rows for each `user` value.

Comment: I am getting an error 'column "user" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function', which is weird since there is no group by...

Comment: That was the unadorned `count(*)`. Now also as a window function, but partitioned over the entire row set (`OVER ()`).

Comment: it runs now, had to add 'distinct' before 'user', because had multiple lines for each user. The percentages don't look right though for some reason...

Comment: You should probably add `DISTINCT ON (user)`. What percentages are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Without using a windowing function or variables, you will need to cross join a grouped subquery on a second "maxed" subquery then select again to return a subset you can work with.

```
SELECT
    B.UserID,
    B.UserCount,
    A.CountAll
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CountAll=SUM(UserCount)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT      
            UserCount=COUNT(*)
        FROM
            MyTable
        GROUP BY
            UserID
    ) AS A    
)AS C
CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT
            UserID,
            UserCount=COUNT(*)
        FROM
            MyTable
        GROUP BY
            UserID
)AS B
```